# How can I put Latex mathematics in the labeling of the axes of a figure?

Tags: plotting, labeling, latex

I want to label my y-axis as $\frac{P}{e^{3N}}$. I just know how to put symbols by using the command; [Phi] as an example. I need a precise command to get the latex math.

Comment: Look at the [MaTeX](https://github.com/szhorvat/MaTeX) package from [Szabolcs](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/12/szabolcs).

Comment: I have 9.1 version of Mathematica.

Comment: @MarcoB MaTeX requires Mathematica 10.0.2 or later. Actually, there is no 9.1 version, only 9.0.1.

Comment: @Jpmg Please clarify what you mean by "Latex mathematics". LaTeX is not necessary to typeset formulae in Mathematica. See http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/TwoDimensionalExpressionInputOverview.html

Comment: @MarcoB I made use of associations for caching results, and they were added only in 10.0 (back in 2014 or so...)

Comment: I want to use the math mode of Latex in labeling the axes of my plots. As I mentioned above, I need to write $\frac{P}{e^{3*N}}$ on the y-axis. I have already seen the possible documentation and answers. If I missed one, please point that out here as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, you can already typeset your labels within Mathematica. For instance:

```
Plot[
 Sin[x], {x, 0, 10},
 Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, False}}, 
 Axes -> False, 
 FrameLabel -> 
  {"", 
   Rotate[
    Style[
     "\!\(\*FractionBox[\(P\), SuperscriptBox[\(e\), \(3  N\)]]\)", 
     Black, 18, FontFamily -> "Times"
    ],
    -90*Degree
   ]
  }
]
```

[image: simple plot with label]

The rather inscrutable portion of the above code (`"\!\(\*FractionBox[\(P\), SuperscriptBox[\(e\), \(3  N\)]]\)"`) was not generated by hand, but instead it was typed in with formatting:

[image: picture of the code that generated the plot above, showing the formatted label as it appears in the notebook]

See also this [Tutorial on input methods for two-dimensional expressions](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/TwoDimensionalExpressionInputOverview.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot @MarcoB, that really helps.